# Conditional Probability Problem With Boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

The problem I am working on is:

> One box contains six red balls and four green balls, and a second box contains seven red balls and three green balls. A ball is randomly chosen from the first box and placed in the
>   second box. Then a ball is randomly selected from the second box and placed in the first box.
>
> a.What is the probability that a red ball is selected from the
>   first box and a red ball is selected from the second box?
>
> b.At the conclusion of the selection process, what is the
>   probability that the numbers of red and green balls in the
>   first box are identical to the numbers at the beginning?

My attempt at part a:

A = choose red ball from box # 1  $P(A)= 6/10=.6$

B = choose red ball from box # 2

So, if it is the case that a red ball was chosen from the first box, then that would increase the total amount of contents of the 2nd box to 11; consequently, it would then be more likely to choose a red ball from the 2nd box.

$P(B|A) = \frac{8/11}{.6} \approx 1.21$

Obviously, this is incorrect, what have I done wrong?

Comment: You don’t want $P(B\mid A)$: you want $P(A\text{ and }B)$, so you should be multiplying: $$\frac6{10}\cdot\frac8{11}=\frac{24}{55}\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How did you generate that grey back-ground?

Comment: With a leading `>`. Click on `edit`, and you can see the current underlying code.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Why exactly is it just a simple multiplication?

Comment: to finish the answer for b: $6/10*8/11+4/10*4/11 = 32/55$

Comment: With probability $3/5$ you get the first red ball. Once you’re in that state, your probability of getting the second red ball is $8/11$. If you think in frequentist terms, on average you’ll get the first red ball $60$% of the time; and $8/11$ of that $60$% you’ll get the second red ball, so you’ll get both $24/55$ of the time.

Comment: P(A and B) = P(A)P(B);  P(A or B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A and B)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, I see. Now, how would I answer the question in the way that I interpreted it; that is, given that the event A has occurred, what is the likelihood that B will occur. How would do accomplish that?

Comment: Once A has occurred, there are $8$ red and $3$ green balls in the second box, so it’s simply $8/11$. (I’ve a feeling that you’re trying to make it harder than it actually is!)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Guilty as charged! Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Eli: You’re welcome.